# Adding support for privileges to an ASP.NET MVC application already supporting roles based authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, permissions, authorization, access-control, roles

I currently have a system where there is a user table, a role table, and a user-roles association table, where one user can be associated to multiple roles (like Admin, BasicUser, etc.). I am able to authorize action methods based on these roles.

Now I want to add support for privileges so that action methods can be restricted based on those as well, rather than just by roles. For example, in a Controller, I may have an HTTPPost action that only someone with a "Write" privilege should be able to perform successfully.

What changes do I need to make so that I can assign privileges to roles? I.E., I want to select the "Admin" role to have the "Write" and "Read" privileges, while a "BasicUser" role will only have a "Read" privilege. This way, an Admin can access any method that is allowed by the Write privilege, while the BasicUser can not.

Answer (score 1):

This could be as simple as hanging a few more fields onto the `Role` table, like `CanRead` and `CanWrite`.  If you want it to be more sophisticated than that, add a `RolePermission` table with a `Role` foreign key.

**See Also**
[Don’t Do Role-Based Authorization Checks; Do Activity-Based Checks](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/).

Comment: Using this approach, how can I restrict an action based on the privilege? Also I wanted to clarify that the CanRead and CanWrite are just two examples out of many possible privileges there can exist in the system.